# In node.js "request.on" what is it this ".on"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new in node.js and java script, i cant find meaning of this ".on" keyword. when i change it with another word code failed.

```
var req = http.get("http://www.google.com", function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

 res.on('data', function (chunk) {
});

}).on('error', function(e) {
console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
 });
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The **on** method **binds** an event to a object.

It is a way to express your intent **if** there is something happening (data sent or error in your case) , **then** execute the function added as a parameter. This style of programming is called **Event-driven programming**. 
You might want to look it up in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)

In node.js, there is a class called **EventEmitter** that provides you with all the code that you need for basic events if you decide to use them in your own code (which I would strongly recommend in the case of node.js). Docs for node.js **EventEmitter** are [here](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

Answer (score 13):

**[.on](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener)** is a method use to bind event handler.

Comment: thank you, i guess i have not oriantate myself with node.js documentation yet.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `stream`. The result of an HTTP request is a readable `stream` and will have all the events and methods associated with such.

Comment: Is there any event to listen when the post request gets completed?

Answer (score 10):

The callback for [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) is invoked with a single argument (which you've named `req`). `req`, short for "request", is a common name, because this argument is an [http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object. The http.ClientRequest object implements [stream.Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), and here's the important bit: all streams are instances of [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).

EventEmitter has a function called [on](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener), which adds a listener function for a specified event.

> "listener function" is just another name for "callback function"

In your example, you've added a listener for the `data` event and the `error` event. Listener functions are *called* (ergo the term "callback") by the EventEmitter.

**Extra Credit**

If you ever need a listener to stop listening (i.e., you no longer want your callback to be called), you can remove a listener with the [emitter.removeListener](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener) function:

```
var myCallback = function(e) { console.log('Got error: ' + e.message); }
res.on('error', myCallback);
// do some things...
res.removeListener('error', myCallback);
```

If you only want a listener to run once, you can use [emitter.once](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener) instead of the `on` function, and then you won't have to remove it:

```
res.once('error', myCallback);
```