# What does adding an event listener ( request.on )to the http request mean ? and wat is the use of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request,response) {
    // Attach listener on end event.
    // This event is called when client sent all data and is waiting for response.
    request.on("end", function(){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/plain"});

        response.end("HELLO HTTP!");
   });

}).listen(8000);
```

PLEASE EXPLAIN ME WHAT DOES  `request.on('end',function(){`  is ? n also if i execute the code with  request.on the webpage is showing page not found. If i remove it its working

Comment: I've read your question several times, but I'm still not sure what exactly you're asking for. You should reformat your question to make it clearer how the code really looks like. Try to structure the content like: introduction to the problem -> the problematic code -> your question concerning the code. If you don't know how to format the question,  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help might be of some help.

Comment: I am very new to node.js so its just an example i got from on of the websites. So my question what is the use of    "request.on"...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the node.js docs.

- Many objects in node emit events - https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events - `.on()` the way of listening for those events(see also [In node.js "request.on" what is it this ".on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892717/in-node-js-request-on-what-is-it-this-on))
- `http.createServer` accepts a function that is added as a handler for the 'request' event - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener
- the `'request'` event passes an `http.IncomingMessage` as the first parameter(`request`) - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request
- `http.incomingMessage` implements the `Readable Stream` interface - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable
- A `Readable Stream` can emit an `'end'` event - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end - which signifies that there is no more data to be read