# POST data handling in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started to learn node few weeks ago, and im finding a problem understanding this part of code , which handle a form POST request :

```
if (req.method === "POST") {
  var postData = "";
  req
    .on("data", function (chunk) {
      postData += chunk;
    })
    .on("end", function () {
      console.log("User Posted:\n" + postData);
      res.end("You Posted:\n" + postData);
    });
}
```

this code prints whatever form input you have
I wanna know how it actually works , especially the part :

```
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    postData += chunk;
}
```

Comment: Use `express` module for your server. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

you will have many methods for get and post. E.g `app.post()` for post req and `app.get()` for get req

Answer (score 0):

The on method binds an event to a object.

In node.js, there is a class called EventEmitter that provides you with all the code that you need for basic events if you decide to use them in your own code (which I would strongly recommend in the case of node.js). Docs for node.js EventEmitter are  https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener

source and same question :

[In node.js "request.on" what is it this ".on"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892717/in-node-js-request-on-what-is-it-this-on)